# In how many ways can four biscuits be chosen from a box containing nine varieties if two each of two varieties are selected?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Textbook Question:

> A large box packet contains nine different kinds of biscuit. In how many way can four biscuits be chosen if:
>  i) two each of two varieties are selected? 
>  ii)three are the same and fourth is different?

i)Reasoning:
Let's say that the nine different kinds of biscuit are : $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I$
. We have to select four biscuits but two of each of the variety that we pick:
So the number of Permutations are: $9.1.8.1 = 72$
Now the number of Combinations are: $\frac{72}{4!} = 3$
Now obviously this answer is wrong and the book says the answer is : $36$
But I don't know how this answer was obtained.

ii)Reasoning:
Let's say that the nine different kinds of biscuit are : $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I$. Again we have to select four biscuits but three of the selected biscuits should be the same while fourth one should be a different one. The number of Permutations are : $9.1.1.8 = 72$. The number of Combinations: $\frac{72}{4!} = 3$. This is also wrong and the book says the answer is : $72$

Comment: For the first case, a selection is entirely specified by specifying the two types of biscuits used.  Thus the answer is $\binom 92$.  The other case is no harder.

Comment: ii-) The first three are the same type , there are $9$ choices for that and the fourth is different  , so we have $8$ choices , then $9 \times 8 =72$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For illustration, imagine the same problem but with a five element set: {A,B,C,D,E}.

Part 1:
As @lulu mentioned, there are two choices that determine the other two choices.  Therefore, you can have: AB,AC,BC,AD,BD,CD,AE,BE,CE,DE as the pairs of two choices.  If order mattered, then we would be able to count the 4-sequences for each pairing, ex: AABB,ABAB,ABBA,BABA,BAAB,BBAA for pairing AB. Since order doesn't matter, these are all equivalent to the subset {A,A,B,B}.  Based on the question's use of "chosen", I am left to assume the sequence does not matter, only the set.  In this case, there are ${5 \choose 2 } = 10$ possible sets, as we enumerated above.

Part 2:
Since we are choosing sets, sequences do not matter.  In this choice, we still choose two elements that determine the set.  If order mattered, we would have sequences like AAAB,AABA,ABAA,BAAA for choice AB.  Since order doesn't matter, these are all equivalent to the subset {A,A,A,B} and the answer is still the same: ${5 \choose 2 } = 10$ possible sets.  However, as pointed out in the comment below, {B,B,B,A} is the other possible subset, so we multiply by two to arrive at 20 possible sets.

Therefore, from the {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I}, your answers are ${9 \choose 2 } = 36$ possible sets for part 1 and ${9 \choose 2 }\times 2=72$ for part 2, and the unique parings come from two choices: AB,AC,BC,AD,BD,CD,AE,BE,CE,DE,AF,BF,CF,DF,EF,AG,BG,CG,DG,EG,FG,AH,BH,CH,DH,EH,FH,GH,AI,BI,CI,DI,EI,FI,GI,HI.

---

Bonus: if order did matter, and we are now talking about sequences:

Part 1: Use the multiplication principle.  We have four locations, and choose two, the other two are determined from the constraint: ${4 \choose 2 } = 6$.  Then, to fill the two chosen locations, we may choose ${5 \choose 2 } = 10$ different pairs.  Therefore, the number of sequences is ${4 \choose 2 } {5 \choose 2 } = 6\times 10 = 60$, which can be written out and verified.

Part 2: Same idea, except now we choose 3 or equivalently, 1: ${4 \choose 3 } = {4 \choose 1 } = 4$ and the number of sequences is ${4 \choose 3 } {5 \choose 2 } = 4\times 10 = 40$.  As in the choice problem, since we could have {A,A,A,B} or {B,B,B,A} from choice AB, we multiply by two again, to arrive at 80 sequences.

Therefore, for your question:

1. ${4 \choose 2 } {9 \choose 2 } = 6\times 36 = 216$
2. ${4 \choose 3 } {9 \choose 2 }\times 2 = 4\times 36 \times 2 = 288$

Comment: Your answer for part two must be multiplied by $2$. Note that after choosing a particular pairing of biscuits from the $36$ (say CF), we can have 3C1F or 1C3F and similarly for all others. This doesn't happen in part one as you have 2 of both.

Comment: Also, order definitely does not matter. The exercise clearly uses the word **chosen**.

Comment: Good point @Cathedral, i only wrote out the 2/2 case and missed the change there.  I updated the response, thank you.